# Conjugate gradient implementation converging on wrong values

Tags: c++, gradient, algebra

I'm trying to write a simple conjugate gradient method function in C++ - pretty simple right? But it literally can't solve any systems of equations. It converges but onto the completely wrong values.

I've written the function out here and provided the main function where I generate positive definite matrix A using symmetric matrix M. I've provided all the code to see if anyone can spot anything wrong. Please don't roast me for doing this - it's a well understand algorithm and it's pointless not providing all the code right? Please assume that the ApplyLHS and innerProduct functions work properly.

```
template <typename TData>
void DoConjGrad(
    std::vector<TData> &in,
    std::vector<TData> &out,
    std::vector<TData> &A
)
{
    TData tol = 10e-8;

    size_t N = in.size();

    std::vector<TData> r(N);
    std::vector<TData> p(N);
    std::vector<TData> w(N);
    size_t k = 0;

    TData rTr;
    TData rTr_prev;
    TData pTw;

    TData alpha;
    TData beta;

    // initial guess for x0
    std::fill(out.begin(), out.end(), 0);

    // r0 = b - Ax0
    ApplyLHS(out, r, A);
    std::transform(in.cbegin(), in.cend(), r.cbegin(), r.begin(), 
        [](const TData &bElem, const TData &rElem){ return bElem - rElem; } );

    // p0 := r0
    std::copy(r.cbegin(), r.cend(), p.begin());

    // calculate (rTr)0
    rTr = innerProduct(r, r);

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
    {
        ApplyLHS(p, w, A);
        pTw = innerProduct(p, w);

        alpha = rTr / pTw;

        std::transform(out.cbegin(), out.cend(), p.cbegin(), out.begin(),
            [alpha](const TData &xElem, const TData &pElem)
            {
                return xElem + alpha*pElem;
            });

        std::transform(r.cbegin(), r.cend(), w.cbegin(), r.begin(),
            [alpha](const TData &rElem, const TData &wElem)
            {
                return rElem - alpha*wElem;
            });

        if (rTr < tol)
            break;

        rTr_prev = rTr;
        rTr = innerProduct(r, r);

        beta = rTr / rTr_prev;

        std::transform(r.cbegin(), r.cend(), p.cbegin(), p.begin(),
            [beta](const TData &rElem, const TData &pElem)
            {
                return rElem + beta*pElem;
            });
    }
}
```

Main:

```
int main()
{
    srand(100);
    size_t N = 2;

    std::vector<double> A(N * N);
    std::vector<double> M(N * N);
    std::vector<double> x_true(N);
    std::vector<double> x_calc(N);
    std::vector<double> b(N);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j <= i; ++j)
        {
            double r = 2*((double)rand())/((double)RAND_MAX) - 1;
            M[i*N + j] = r;
            M[j*N + i] = r;
        }
    
    // get positive semi-definite matrix = M.T @ M
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < N; ++j)
            for (int k = 0; k < N; ++k)
                A[i*N + j] = M[k*N + i] * M[k*N + j];

    // generate random x
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        x_true[i] = 2*((double)rand())/((double)RAND_MAX) - 1;

    // calculate b
    ApplyLHS(x_true, b, A);

    // solve for x calc
    DoConjGrad<double>(b, x_calc, A);
}
```

Helper functions:

```
template <typename TData>
void printMat(
    size_t nr,
    size_t nc,
    std::vector<TData> &mat
)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < nr; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < nc; ++j)
        {
            std::cout.precision(5);
            std::cout.width(10);
            std::cout << mat[i*nc + j] << "\t";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}

template <typename TData>
void ApplyLHS(
    std::vector<TData> &in,
    std::vector<TData> &out,
    std::vector<TData> &A
)
{
    size_t N = in.size();
    std::fill(out.begin(), out.end(), 0);

    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    for (int j = 0; j < N; ++j)
        out[i] += in[j] * A[i*N + j];
}

template <typename TData>
TData innerProduct(
    std::vector<TData> &a,
    std::vector<TData> &b
)
{
    TData result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); ++i)
    {
        result += a[i] * b[i];
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Groovy. That gets the trivial stuff out of the way. [Few compiler warnings](https://godbolt.org/z/v8zcT98K7), but nothing important (unless the numbers get unexpectedly large).

Comment: Yeah as you can probably tell I normally have the compiler warnings switched off -- what you don't know can't hurt you right? :-( Grateful if you're able to figure out what's causing this issue!

Comment: You might be surprised how much debugging those warnings can eliminate. In this case they're telling you that the upper bound of the for loops could be much larger than the value trying to reach that upper bound, possibly resulting in an infinite loop. if `i` is an int and can only reach 2,147,483,647 and `N` could conceivably be 18,446,744,073,709,551,615, you could have a problem. Very unlikely in this case.

Comment: What I generally do is build a table of expectations and start stepping the code with a 
 debugger until I see the expectations violated.

Comment: I see, yes I will do that in the future. These cases are for tiny numbers though, it must be something else in the code. I've tried on lots of different matrices so I doubt it can be condition number causing the problem.

Comment: Instead of random values, please provide a fixed example of input, expected output and what the code produce.

Comment: Okay: A:

      [[0.09,           -0.03]
     [-0.03,            0.01]]
b:

   [-0.0075,
    0.0025]
x_true:

         [0,
      0.25]
x_calc:

    [-0.075,
     0.025]

Comment: Gradient descent does not necessarily converge and when it does, it's not necessarily to the global optimum of the considered function. Everything depends on the function properties. Thus even if you fix all the possible bugs, you still may not obtain the expected output. I can't see in your code what is your objective function. Be sure it's a convex one if you want to debug a simple case.

Comment: This isn't gradient descent, it's conjugate gradient method for solving a linear system Ax = b. It converges for positive definite matrices A. In this case it's converging but to the wrong values and I can't figure out why.

Comment: Your specific example isn’t strictly positive definite. If you consider the vector x=[1,3] then xT.A.x = 0. Try adding something to a diagonal element.

Comment: Please note that the rows of the example you posted in the comments aren't linearly independent, so that *both* [0, 0.25] and [-0.075, 0.025] are solutions. If you consider A:=[[A: [[**0.9**, -0.03] [-0.03, 0.01]] instead, you (should) get [0, 0.25].

Comment: This is a feature of the code which is always going to happen, @Bob__ - see my subsequent answer.

Comment: Yes my issue is the generation of positive definite matrices. This has been fixed and now the code works properly. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the good news first: there appears to be NOTHING WRONG with your conjugate-gradient algorithm! (Well, nothing causing it to fail anyway. Personally, I would make the tolerance smaller, and move the loop exit condition after the point where you calculate rTr.)

If you calculate the determinant of A from your code ... you will find that det(A)=0 every time, regardless of the value of N. (So A is singular; there is some non-zero x such that Ax=0 and hence xT.A.x=0: thus A isn't strictly positive definite either, which is a condition for the CG algorithm).

But a major clue is that the determinant of M is not (usually) zero ... and yet det(A) should be det(M) squared.

So, look at your matrix multiplication for A = M<sup>T</sup>M. It is not correct; (each element should be initialised and then formed from a sum). Change this part to the following and you are good to go.

```
// get positive semi-definite matrix = Mtranspose * M
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < N; ++j)
    {
        A[i*N+j] = 0;                                     // CAREFUL!!
        for (int k = 0; k < N; ++k)                       // ""  
            A[i*N + j] += M[k*N + i] * M[k*N + j];        // ""
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow this was literally driving me crazy and the error was so ludicrous! Thanks for your help!